# Calculate the integral $\int_S (x^2+y^2)dxdy$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Calculate the integral $\int_S (x^2+y^2)dxdy$; S is the square of side 2 centered at (1,0), edges parallel to the axes.

I wanted to confirm on how to compute the following integral correctly.

For example, given it has a side length of 2 then the square is in the upper right quadrant?

This gives me:
$$\int_0^2\int_0^2(x^2+y^2)dydx$$

This assumes $0 <x<2$ and $0 < y < 2.$

Although something does not seem right here for me.

Comment: I see nothing wrong with that, although I would write $0\leqslant x\leqslant2$ and $0\leqslant y\leqslant2$.

Comment: You'd want $-1\leq y \leq 1$?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Ah Okay! I've been integrating some weird shapes lately so I think the simplicity of this threw my off!

Comment: @kingW3 Yes! I wrote as if the center of the square was $(1,1)$.

Comment: @kingW3 Ah okay this makes better sense now. Thanks for clarifying